# MySQL Docker file : sed: couldn't open temporary file

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I am trying to create new MySQL image and deploying in Kubernetes.

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
USER root
ARG MYSQL_SERVER_PACKAGE=mysql-community-server-minimal-8.0.19
ARG MYSQL_SHELL_PACKAGE=mysql-shell-8.0.19

# Install server
RUN yum install -y https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-minimal-release-el7.rpm \
      https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7.rpm \
  && yum-config-manager --enable mysql80-server-minimal \
  && yum install -y \
      $MYSQL_SERVER_PACKAGE \
      $MYSQL_SHELL_PACKAGE \
      libpwquality \
  && yum clean all \
  && mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY healthcheck.sh /healthcheck.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD /healthcheck.sh
EXPOSE 3306 33060

RUN chmod +rwx /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +rwx /healthcheck.sh

RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

It's working fine in the container. But throwing error when I deployed in Kubernetes like below:

[image]

How can I understand this issue?

**ADDED**

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
if [ -n "$MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE" ] || [ -n "console" ]; then
        # Don't touch bind-mounted config files
        if ! cat /proc/1/mounts | grep "/etc/my.cnf"; then
            sed -i 's/^log-error=/#&/' /etc/my.cnf
        fi
fi
```

P.S : I have added content of the file.

Comment: Could you show us the content of `entrypoint.sh` script ? Apparently it uses `sed` to perform some operations but why are there any temporary files saved into `/etc` directory ? There are a lot of better locations for that like `/tmp` which won't require privilege escalation.

Comment: If you have more questions regarding Docker, please consider following this site https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124022/docker-container/

Comment: I have added content @mario

Comment: The fact that you have `kubernetes` in your tags implies that you are running that docker image in kubernetes, which very likely either has a volume mount for `/etc` or has a `securityContext:` that has switched the user the container is running as (likely to the `mysql` user shown in your `Dockerfile`); you'll need to include those relevant details to get an answer

Answer (score 6):

The problem is related with `sed`'s `in-place` editing implementation. When you edit a file using the `-i` or `--in-place` option, the edition doesn't actually happen `in-place`. `sed` saves the changes into a temporary file and then uses it to replace the original one.

It happens that you don't have write permission to `/etc` directory, where `sed` is trying to create its temporary file.

As suggested in comments most probably the command is run by user `mysql`. For sure it is not run as `root` as it has enough privileges to be able to write to `/etc`:

```
bash-4.2# ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 27 15:04 /etc
```

As you can see `others` don't have write permission. Changing permissions or owner of `/etc` directory itself is a really bad idea and I won't advise you to run this command as `root` user either.

The simplest solution is to give up on using `--in-place` option, save the result in a directory such as `/tmp`, to which everyone has access:

```
bash-4.2# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Mar 27 16:39 /tmp
```

and after that replace the content of the original file with the content of the temporary one.

Your command may look like this:

```
sed 's/^log-error=/#&/' /etc/my.cnf > /tmp/my.cnf && cat /tmp/my.cnf > /etc/my.cnf
```

#### One important caveat:

You need to make sure you have `write` permission on `/etc/my.cnf` file. As you can see below, by default you don't have such permission either, so the error will occur later, when the command will try to write to the original config file.

```
bash-4.2# ls -l /etc/my.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1239 Mar 27 15:04 /etc/my.cnf
```

You need to modify it in your `Dockerfile` either by making it availeble for edit by everyone:

```
RUN chmod 666 /etc/my.cnf
```

or better option:

```
RUN chown mysql /etc/my.cnf
```

to change its owner to `mysql`, if this is the user that executes the `entrypoint.sh` script.

Please let me know if it helps.